# How to capture image using camera and send to firebase

Tags: java, android, image, firebase, capture

I am capturing images by using camera and want to send to firebase storage. But I am getting error by 3 three days. I am stuck on it. When I fire intent it captures image, but in onActivityresult it returns request code=1 and result code=-1. Here is my code

Donation Activity:

```
    package com.example.manzoorhussain.kindnessapp;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DonationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button mUploadBtn;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private final static int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private StorageReference mstorage;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Uri photoURI;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_donation);

        mUploadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mstorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mUploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dispatchTakePictureIntent();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + photoURI, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StorageReference filepath = mstorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(DonationActivity.this, "Upload Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(DonationActivity.this, "Upload Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
// Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

// Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
// Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File...
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                //takePictureIntent.setData(photoURI);
                // takePictureIntent.putExtra("imageUri", photoURI.toString());

                takePictureIntent.putExtra("imageUri", photoURI.toString());

                // takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am getting error in activity resultcode that is equal to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW AFAIK,

```
public static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
public static final int RESULT_CANCELED = 0;
```

Just press ctrl + B on RESULT_OK if you are on Windows machine**
So maybe you are somehow cancelling activity the activity before it gets completed. I have done something similar. After your video/photo is taken, wait for the OS to display a tick or something to select that picture taken. Here is my code if it helps.

Try this

```
/**
     * Upload a video directly by recording it using camera
     * You can do image/video whatever you require
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent recordVideoIntent = new Intent();
        recordVideoIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (recordVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(recordVideoIntent, UPLOAD_VIDEO_CAMERA);
        }
    }
```

//Make the network call in a Loader or Async Task

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, UploadVideo.this);
```

//And inside your AsyncTask or Loader, do something like this. You made a function to rename your file. It is not needed I guess. The file is stored automatically in your phone AFAIK. And regarding the name of file in Firebase STorage, just use something like this

```
       //Upload the video to storage
        StorageReference mFirebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mFirebaseStorageRef
                .child(String.valueOf(mCurrentUser.getEmail() + new Date().getTime()))
                .putFile(videoData).
                addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        try {

                            //MAYBE UPDATE IT SOMEPLACE IN DATABASE AS WELL
                            HashMap<String, String> city_Obj = new HashMap<String,String>();
                            city_Obj.put("VIDEO_URL", downloadUrl);
                            city_Obj.put("VIDEO_NAME", nameOfVideo);
                            city_Obj.put("VIDEO_DESC", descriptionOfVideo);
                            dbRef.child("CITIES").child(spinnerCityName).push().setValue(city_Obj);


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.getMessage());
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am capturing the image just as you are with saving the image to the file system before uploading, but using the **mCurrentPhotoPath** to load the Bitmap instead.  Then convert the Bitmap to bytes and upload to Firebase Storage from there.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("photo");
        UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putBytes(imageBytes);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new 
        OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
             @Override
             public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.d("UploadComplete", "Image successfully uploaded URL: %s", taskSnaphot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
             }
        });
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        onCancel();
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String ts = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String filename = String.format("JPEG_%s_", ts);
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(filename, ".jpg", storageDir);
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

To break it down further in my application I am first displaying the image within an ImageView and then when uploaded converting it to byte[] like this.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable().getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

And then upload to Firebase.

```
StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("photo");
UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putBytes(imageBytes);
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.d("UploadComplete", "Image successfully uploaded URL: %s", taskSnaphot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My example hope you understand it.

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        progressDialog.setMessage(UPLOADING);
        progressDialog.show();
        StorageReference filePath = storageRef.child(STORAGE_FOLDER_NAME).child(recipeTitle.getText().toString());
        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(CreateNewRecipeActivity.this, UPLOAD_COMPLETE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir i have already done this but it still throwing exception at image url

Comment: try debug and see what url you are getting

Comment: is it textview in which you stored uri of image?

Comment: in my case uri is null sir. May store image in a textview and then assign to child?

Comment: no im just sending in to storage im not setting it in textview. Try debug this: uri.getLastPathSegment()

Comment: after debugging it throws  null object reference error at uri.getLastPathSegment()

Comment: Can you send me a complete sample please. because i am stuck on it since three days and i have enough time to complete the task

Comment: try change this:  uri.getLastPathSegment()  to a string like my example and see if you can upload